US visa in old passport
My old Indian passport was cancelled when a new one was issued. The last two pages of the expired passport have been stapled by the embassy (cover and lamination page). The expired passport has a valid US visa with which I have travelled. When I apply for B2 visa renewal, the old passport is also asked to be submitted.
Will the two stapled pages in old passport be an issue? Can I remove the staples before submission to the US embassy?

Keep the staples. You didn't put there, so it is not your task to remove things officials did to your passport.

@GiacomoCatenazzi you've posted an answer in the comment box.

@GiacomoCatenazzi that's not strictly true. Thailand immigration sometimes likes to staple your entry/exit form/slip to a page in your passport until you exit (this practice in general makes me sad), and once, they removed the form/slip but kept the staple in place, which looked more suspicious/damaged than two holes (plus discouraged stamping that page), so I just carefully removed it without damaging the passport (by folding open the metal ends and carefully lifting it out, doing it otherwise would be damaging). I think it was my task, and I don't think anyone'd be angry at me for it.

Give both of your passports as is to the US embassy. They would have come across previous applications just as yours, where the passport have been stapled just like yours. With this, the embassy could do one of three things:

Remove the staples on your behalf
Ask you to remove the staples before accepting the passports
Won't be an issue, staples won't be required to be removed

It's more than likely they'll do the first one. However if you want to have peace of mind, it might be at your interest to give the US embassy a call, and ask them the question.
